# htaccess redirect site root to public_html folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, public

When users go to foo.com/bar they should see the site located in foo.com/bar/public. The public part has to be hidden. How can I achieve this using .htaccess?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/bar/public/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/bar/public/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^/?bar/(.*)$ /bar/public/$1 [L]
```

The first condition checks that the URI starts with "/bar", then groups the rest of the request. The next 2 conditions checks that the rest of the request (backreferenced by `%1`) maps to either an existing file or directory. If all conditions are met, then it rewrites the URI internally into `/bar/public`.